# ExecuteNonQuery() returning -1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am calling a SQL Server stored procedure from C#, consisting of a straightforward INSERT statement.
The ExecuteNonQuery() returns the number of rows affected by the statement OK unless there is no update, in which case I'm getting -1.

This doesn't make much sense to me; how can -1 rows be affected?

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794097/executenonquery-returns-1-always

Comment: I'd read about the NOCOUNT and had tried it with no change; if one record added, returns 1 correctly but if 0 rows added, returns -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The @@ROWCOUNT function is updated even when SET NOCOUNT is ON.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259204%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

So, since you are at a dead-end with turning `NOCOUNT` off, try this:

**Use `@@ROWCOUNT` with `ExecuteNonQuery`**

At the end of your SP, execute `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` and use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`. This will return the result that you desire.

Answer (score 1):

You can get -1 after calling ExecuteNonQuery() with stored procedure having insert/delete/update query. This happens if stored procedure do not call any query(Insert/Update/Delete). Here is one example which will help you to understand this.

**StoredProcedure-** MySQL

DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_DML $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_DML
    (
      **P_Operation** varchar(50)
    )
BEGIN

```
  if(P_Operation='Insert')
    /*  Insert Statment*/
  end if;

  if(P_Operation='Update')
    /*  Update Statment*/
    end if;
  if(P_Operation='Delete')
    /*Delete Statment*/
    end if;
```

END$$

If u call this SP using **ExecuteNonQuery();** and passing parameter **P_Operation as 'NoOpeartion'** which does not satisfy any condition written into Stored procedure then it will always return **-1**.